# How to relayout views on ViewWIllAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have following code inside `ViewWillAppear`:

```
CGFloat typeViewHeight = self.scrollview.frame.size.height;
CGFloat typeViewWidth = 120;

for (UIView *view in [self.scrollview subviews]) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[TypeSelectionItemView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < typeArray.count; ++i) {
    TypeSelectionItemView *typeView = nil;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(typeViewWidth * i, 0, typeViewWidth, typeViewHeight);
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TypeSelectionItemView" owner:self options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TypeSelectionItemView class]]){
            typeView = (TypeSelectionItemView *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    [self.typeScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(typeViewWidth * (i + 1), typeViewHeight)];
    [self.typeScrollView addSubview:typeView];
}
```

Subviews position and size are not correct when I see in application, however, if I place it inside `ViewDidAppear`, subviews position and size are correct, but views are too late to be displayed to user.

Is there any way to solve it by still putting those code inside `ViewWillAppear`?

I have tried these code inside `ViewWillAppear` but doesn't work at all:

```
[self.typeScrollView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.typeScrollView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self.typeScrollView setNeedsLayout];
[self.typeScrollView layoutSubviews];
[self.typeScrollView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Place your code inside `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` method instead of `ViewWillAppear`

Comment: Then it will be called multiple times. One time call only inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews` does not help

Comment: @Rendy Move your code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and use a boolean to check and make it call only one time.

Comment: Try the suggestion by @trungduc. It should work

Comment: Yes it works already.. Earlier there was another issue too, so managed to fix both of them.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your codes in `ViewWillAppear` to `ViewWillLayoutSubview`. 
And if you need to get the real frame/size of any view before `ViewDidAppear`. 
Just put these two lines above:

```
// Force scrollView to layout subview
scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
// ...
```

Hope it is useful!